# Issue with neethi jar in WAS7

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, websphere-7

I am deploying a SOAP based webservice client on WAS7. I am able to consume service from my machine by deploying client on Tomcat 8.0 but I am getting errors related to neethi jar on WAAS7.

Error: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactory

So I went through several articles on net but nothing seems to help. I have tried changing the class loader policy to "parent_last" for my module but it as suggested in one of the stackoverflow questions but it didn't work.

[Incompatible neethi.jar with WAS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568330/incompatible-neethi-jar-with-was-7)

I have tried following :
(a) change the class loader policy
(b)change the manifest file to include "DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true"
(c) tried using CXF 2.7.5 with neethi 3.0.2 and xmlschema-core 2.0.3

Any info/help is much appreciated.

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incompatible neethi.jar with WAS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568330/incompatible-neethi-jar-with-was-7)

Comment: As mentioned above i have been through that questions and changing the class loader policy doesn't help. There is no neethi jar present in WAS lib so duplicate jar should not be any issue