# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactory

Tags: java, cxf, junit4

I have a problem with a junit test. Neethi-3.0.1.jar and cxf-rt-core-2.7.4.jar are included in my project's Maven Dependencies. These jars should be compatible. However I still get java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactory
at at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension 
so I assume I am somehow still have an older version of neethi on the classpath.
How do I fix it?

I see a similar question answered but it was running in WAS and not junit.
[Incompatible neethi.jar with WAS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568330/incompatible-neethi-jar-with-was-7/32124600?noredirect=1#comment52141626_32124600)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it helps, but the same (as WAS CL order setting) may be done as:

```
<container-descriptor>  
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.cxf.endpoint.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.cxf.frontend.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.cxf.transport.http.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.cxf.interceptor.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.cxf.transports.http.configuration.*</package-name>
       </prefer-application-packages>
    ...
```

of weblogic.xml WLS web app config. file for

Answer (score 0):

rearranging the order of dependencies in the pom resolved the problem.

Comment: Could you specify how were the dependencies reordered?

Comment: I added dependencies that were dependent of cxf to the bottom of my pom file. I have to assume that another dependency was brining in the old version of neethi but by placing these other dependencies after them I was able to overlay the old verison of netthi wit ha new one provided by one of these dependencies. I hope that expalins my solution.