# CXF running on WEBSPHERE

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, cxf

I developped an apllication with `CXF` for calling web services and creating web services. When i tried to deploy this application under `websphere` with using `Websphere console`, it gave the following error :

```
 [8/25/15 23:00:05:327 ICT] 000004f9 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
    [8/25/15 23:00:05:329 ICT] 000004f9 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[cxf]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.RetroDao com..retroDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cxf' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1651)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1170)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:638)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:769)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1364)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2169)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
            at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5429)
            at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5555)
            at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1256)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
            at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
            at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
            at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
            at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
            at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
            at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
            at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
            at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
            at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
            at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
            at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
            at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
            at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
            at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
            at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
            at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.RetroDao com.retroDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cxf' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
            ... 68 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cxf' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:735)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:666)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:507)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:317)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:185)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:829)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
            ... 70 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
            ... 84 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
            ... 92 more
    Caused by: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
            at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:182)
            at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.getClassObject(Extension.java:194)
            at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.activateAllByType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:142)
            at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:126)
            at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:138)
            at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus.<init>(SpringBus.java:46)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
            ... 94 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactory
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:262)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:852)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:762)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:585)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:262)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:852)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:762)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:585)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
            at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:163)
            ... 104 more
```

Here is `my cxf-bean.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

</beans>
```

And here is my `application-context.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
    ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

</beans>
```

I used parent class loader from websphere.But it did not work for me. What should I do ?

Comment: is it localhost or test server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568330/incompatible-neethi-jar-with-was-7

Comment: it is test server @sgpalit.

Comment: @MagicWand it is not related question . My question is different according to content.

Comment: Actualy @MagicWand has directed you to correct answer please read accepted answer carefully. Stacktraces are same...

Comment: @sgpalit thanks for reply! My wild guess is that you have packed geronimo and StAX JARs together with your app, and as referenced post explains, WAS already has a version of these classes in its internal JARs. So please try to remove JARs and set WAR classloader policy to PARENT_LAST and see if it helps in problem solving.

Comment: Set that Parent_Last on the web module level, not application.

Comment: I am checking @sgpalit

Comment: @MagicWand it did not worked for me ...

Comment: @sgpalit it did not worked for me ...

Comment: Did the error changed or is it the same?

Comment: Check loaded classes Troubleshooting -> Class Loader Viewer -> server_name -> Applications -> your_webapp

Comment: The error is the same as before @sgpalit

Comment: When i checked loaded classes, what should i look for ? @sgpalit

Comment: Check if your neethi jar is loaded, **org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactory**

Comment: Yes, it is loaded 3.0.3 version of neethi. @sgpalit

Comment: Check that it is parent_last and check for these jars it should not exists, geronimo-servlet
geronimo-javamail
stax-api

Comment: I have already checked. it is parent_last and the jars you ve talked about i have already  deleted them. @sgpalit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem and after searching on the web found a working solution for me.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568330/incompatible-neethi-jar-with-was-7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSfXD.png)

In addition to this solution you have to change class loading order as 'classes loaded with local class loader first' under the manage modules tab.Because was has it's jar that conflicts you jars when you select this option all jars on the was will be suppressed.

[image]